# How to fix amplify CLI error : "-bash: amplify: command not found"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, npm-install, aws-amplify

I had installed amplify cli on my laptop and even though it threw errors, I had used the `amplify configure` command anyway and it worked. But now when I'm trying to do the same thing on a different laptop it is throwing the error "-bash: amplify: command not found". Below is the entire error block :

```
npm WARN deprecated @types/ora@3.2.0: This is a stub types definition. ora provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
/Users/.npm-global/bin/amplify -> /Users/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/bin/amplify

> snappy@5.0.5 install /Users/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/snappy
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/snappy/build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/snappy
gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 

> zmq@2.15.3 install /Users/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/zmq
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/zmq/build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/zmq
gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 

> @aws-amplify/cli@3.11.0 postinstall /Users/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli
> node scripts/post-install.js

Ignore installation errors for optional dependencies: gyp, fs-ext


----------------------------------------
Successfully installed the Amplify CLI
----------------------------------------


Javascript Getting Started - https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/start


Android Getting Started - https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/start


iOS Getting Started - https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/start


npm WARN @conduitvc/mosca@2.8.3 requires a peer of leveldown@~1.4.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @conduitvc/mosca@2.8.3 requires a peer of ioredis@^1.15.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @conduitvc/mosca@2.8.3 requires a peer of mongodb@~2.1.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: snappy@5.0.5 (node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/snappy):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: snappy@5.0.5 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: zmq@2.15.3 (node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/zmq):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: zmq@2.15.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

+ @aws-amplify/cli@3.11.0
```

amplify commands are working totally fine on the other laptop which spat the same errors as above. I had even tried installing the cli using `npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli --unsafe-perm=true` as suggested by a user on GitHub. If someone could help me fix this it'd be really great. TIA

Comment: You may need to do `sudo npm install -g ...`

Comment: Tried that as well. Tried reinstalling node, tried changing the owner using sudo chown -R ownername: /usr/local/lib/node_modules, tried installing typescript (a user on GitHub suggested), and yet none of these worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After spending a decent amount of time trying to analyse the errors, the following finally worked for me :

1. Installed typescript
2. Added `/usr/local/bin/node` and `/usr/local/bin/npm` to the path
3. Made sure the admin is in charge to access the file by using the command :

   `sudo chown -R ownername: /usr/local/lib/node_modules`
4. Finally installed amplify using this command :

`sudo npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli --unsafe-perm=true`

By following these steps, even though i'm getting errors, the amplify commands are working.

Comment: didn't worked for me

Comment: I was of the understanding using sudo is not ideal with npm, this will cause more grief.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I found  was at the end of the npm install, you can see the path that it gets installed too.

```sh
/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.8.0/bin/amplify -> /usr/local/Cellar/node/13.8.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/bin/amplify
```

you can manually append this to you path by running the command:

```sh
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.8.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/bin/
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, first I had to run it from where it was installed.

```sh
/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/bin/amplify
```

run above command (**Path of amplify-cli installation (You may have a different location)**) once.

HOLA!! Now try `amplify` as a command it would start working :]

Answer (score 0):

NPM amplify package was not working for me, so:

```
npm uninstall amplify -g
```

...also:

```
which amplify
```

then:

```
sudo rm -rf /<your path>/bin/amplify
```

Finally:

```
 brew install aws-amplify
```